# Spring MVC Service Junit Test Case

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am having a Java Spring MVC application. Here is my Service class.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.integration.Message;
import org.springframework.integration.MessagingException;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmailService implements MessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("receiveChannel")
    private DirectChannel messageChannel;

    private final Log logger = LogFactory
        .getLog(EmailService.class);

    public void init() {
        messageChannel.subscribe(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
         logger.info("Message: " + message);

    }
}
```

I want to write a Test Case for the above class. This is what I have tried

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

//other imports

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @Test
    public void testEmailService() throws Exception {
        emailService=Mockito.spy(new EmailService());
        Mockito.doNothing().when(emailService).init();
    }
}
```

In my **applicationcontext.xml**, I am specifying one Gmail and its password (Its IMAP Access is enabled)

What it should is when I send some message in that mail from other mails, it should just log the message (implemented in the other method of Service class)

When I run the test case, it shows test case is success. But when I run any message to that mail id, it is not printing in my console.

Comment: The test case does not test anything, of course it successful. When nothing can't fail, nothing fails :)
Where do you send a message in the test case?

Comment: I should send to the email from another email. Then the method should print the email. I have put a `system.out.println("init")` as the first line in the `init()` method of the service class. It was not printing. Why? What am I doing wrong in Test Case?

Comment: I think that's because you're calling `doNothing()` and not the actual method

Comment: I removed `doNothing()`. Then it is showing `The method init() is undefined for the type OngoingStubbing<EmailService>` in the eclipse. It shows the option for casting

Comment: Where is Spring MVC in this Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you loading context? If this is not an integration test you don't need one(remember unit tests need to be fast and not load/connect to external resources).
Anyway, I suggest you use `Mockito` to mock `DirectChannel` and verify interactions then.

Here's how I would test `init()` method:

```
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Mock
    DirectChannel messageChannel;//you 

    @InjectMocks
    EmailService emailService;

    @Test
    public void shouldSubscribeToSelf(){
       //call method under test
       emailService.init();
       //verify behavior
       Mockito.verify(messageChannel).subscribe(emailService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @isah pointed out I think you are confused between Mock Unit testing and Spring Integration testing (usually the two are mutually exclusive).

Since @isah pointed out the mock way here is the correct way to do it integration test wise:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

//other imports

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:webapptest")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @Test
    public void testEmailService() throws Exception {
        //Spring will automatically wire in emailService.
        emailService.init();
        //validate initialization through whatever external way you can or just be satisified that it didn't throw an exception
    }
}
```

However my gut is that your `init()` method should be marked `@PostConstruct` in which case spring will do this automatically for you and thus is not a good method to test (since it will be executed on test startup).